# Sprint Boot WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

## Background

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring MVC and the Spring Boot Actuator with management endpoints. I am using a custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to use form based login, require that all requests (other than login) are authenticated and use a custom UserDetailsService to pull the users out of my MongoDB datasource.

## The Problem

As soon as I use a custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I can no longer access any of the management of health endpoints. I also see this in the logs:

```
    WARN .EndpointWebMvcChildContextConfiguration : 
No single bean of type ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
found (this might make some endpoints inaccessible without authentication)
```

I am slightly confused by this message since I haven't configured my own ManagementAdapter. Even if I do authenticate I still **cannot access** endpoints such as `/health` or `/beans` (but I can access other custom application endpoints.

## What I'd Like To Achieve

Ideally, I'd like to configure the actuator and my application separately.

I'd like to just use the standard `ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration` to configure an in memory authentication realm use with basic authentication just for the management endpoints and continue to use for form based login with custom user details service for all application endpoints.

Is there anyway that I can achieve this? If it is relevant I run actuator on a different port (`management.port=8081`) so if there is a way to configure the two ports differently then this might work.

## The Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @EnableWebSecurity
  @EnableWebMvcSecurity
  public static class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserLookupService userLookupService;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationEventSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.userDetailsService(userLookupService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .csrf().disable();

      http.formLogin()
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/user/login").permitAll()
        .successHandler(authenticationEventSuccessHandler);

      http.logout().logoutUrl("/user/logout").permitAll();
    }
  }

  @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
  public static class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
  }
}
```

## Edits

1. The log warning comes from having `management.security.enabled=false` in my application.properties. The reason I had this was because I was having trouble accessing the endpoints I wanted access for development.
2. For some unknown reason I can't use the same configuration in my sample application. In my original application I use the code:

   @Autowired
       public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(userLookupService)
           .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
       }

But in this app this causes the following exception:

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer@3c443976 to already built object
```

So to fix this instead I have to override the `protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method instead. I don't know why this is, the only real difference I can think of is that my original app is a multi-module Maven project and perhaps there is some difference in the order modules are being configured.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem that you've described including the warning message about duplicate ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter beans. What you've shared above isn't all that's needed to create a functioning app so I may have missed something. Can you share a simplified project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have created one [here](https://github.com/davidgoate/spring-security-demo) I have also added an edit above as I discovered a few things in the process of creating this demo app.

Comment: It all seems to work fine for me, i.e. I can access /health, /beans, /env etc on 8081 once I've authenticated.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Yes, I think that this demonstrates that there is something wrong with my other application. Unfortunately, I don't currently know the cause (it is interesting to me that I can't use the same `configureGlobal` method) . If you got a chance to look at the edits you might have seen the cause of the original warning message. I'd still like to investigate what options are available to configure the Actuator separately from the app. e.g. two different authentication managers and one with form based security, the other with HTTP Basic.